# How do I solve "ResourceInitializationError" error for Task execution in ECS on Fargate?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

### What I want to do

I want to create Node.js (built with Nest.js) server in the infrastructure as follows:

[infra-structure-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz8RW.png)

GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/Fanta335/cdk-ecs-nest-app).

**Notice:**

- ECS is settled in private subnet.
- I want to use private link to connect with AWS services (ECR and S3 in my case) rather than NAT gateway in public subnet.
- Infrastructure is built from CloudFormation stack in AWS CDK Toolkit.
- Node.js server is a simple app that responses 'Hello World!'.

### Current behavior

When I deploy the AWS CloudFormation stack with `cdk deploy`, it is stuck in the ECS service creation at `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS` state. I can see ECS task execution error logs in ECS management console as follows:

```
STOPPED (ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 3 time(s): RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://api.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp 99.77.62.61:443: i/o timeout)
```

If I don't delete stack or set minimum number of task to `0`, ECS service continuously try to execute tasks for hours and finally get timeout error.

I have already checked some points based on [this official article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-pull-container-error/?nc1=h_ls).

- Create VPC endpoints (`com.amazonaws.region.ecr.dkr`, `com.amazonaws.region.ecr.api`, `S3`)
- Configure VPC endpoints (security group, subnets to settle in, IAM policy)
- Add permissions to ECS task execution role so that ECS can pull image from ECR
- Check if the image exists in ECR

And I have checked 'hello world' with this docker image in local machine.

### Reproduction Steps

A minimal GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/Fanta335/cdk-ecs-nest-app).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Fanta335/cdk-ecs-nest-app
$ cd cdk-ecs-nest-app
$ npm install
```

AWS CDK toolkit is used in this project, so you need to run `npm install -g aws-cdk` if you have not installed AWS CDK toolkit in your local machine.

And if you have not set default IAM user configuration in aws cli, you need to run `aws configure` in order to pass environment variables to the CloudFormation stack.

```
$ cdk deploy
```

Then the deployment should be stuck.

### Versions

- MacOS Monterey 12.6
- AWS CDK cli 2.43.1 (build c1ebb85)
- AWS cli aws-cli/2.7.28 Python/3.9.11 Darwin/21.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
- Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
- Nest cli 9.1.3

Comment: There's something wrong with your ECR VPC endpoint. You need to double check the security group assigned to the endpoint, and also check that you have DNS resolution enabled in your VPC. Check all the "Considerations for Amazon ECR VPC endpoints" here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Deployment has been succeeded! The problem was 
DNS resolution has not been enabled in ECR VPC endpoints as you said. I should have set `privateDnsEnabled: true` manually to  the `InterfaceVpcEndpoint` instances in CDK CloudFormation stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was DNS resolution has not been enabled in ECR VPC endpoints. I should have set `privateDnsEnabled: true` manually to the `InterfaceVpcEndpoint` instances in `cdk-ecs-nest-app-stack.ts` file as follows:

```
    const ECSPrivateLinkAPI = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, "ECSPrivateLinkAPI", {
      vpc,
      service: new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointService(`com.amazonaws.${REGION}.ecr.api`),
      securityGroups: [securityGroupPrivateLink],
      privateDnsEnabled: true, // HERE
    });
    const ECSPrivateLinkDKR = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, "ECSPrivateLinkDKR", {
      vpc,
      service: new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointService(`com.amazonaws.${REGION}.ecr.dkr`),
      securityGroups: [securityGroupPrivateLink],
      privateDnsEnabled: true, // HERE
    });
```

According to the [CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint.html#privatednsenabled), the default value of `privateDnsEnabled` is defined by the service which uses this VPC endpoint.

> privateDnsEnabled? 
> Type: boolean (optional, default: set by the instance of IInterfaceVpcEndpointService, or true if not defined by the instance of IInterfaceVpcEndpointService)

I didn't checked the default `privateDnsEnabled` values of `com.amazonaws.${REGION}.ecr.api` and `com.amazonaws.${REGION}.ecr.dkr` but we have to set `true` manually in CDK Toolkit.